# Why does Nodejs use more than one CPU?

Tags: node.js

There are a lot of answers explaining why Nodejs only uses one CPU, however I couldn't find an answer to why it would use more than one, considering that I have neither forked any child processes nor enabled cluster mode.

Running `htop` shows me that both of my CPUs are running concurrently (continuously alternating noticeably between each other -- first CPU goes to 80% while the second CPU runs at 5%, and then alternates to first CPU running at around 5%, while second takes 80%), and I have no other processes running on my server.

Why is this happening? I should note `nodemon` is currently running, but I've tried just running `node index`, and the result is the same. No `pm2`, no other apps are running.

```
root@server:~# sudo ps -a
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 129938 pts/8    00:00:00 npm run dev
 129952 pts/8    00:00:00 sh
 129953 pts/8    00:00:00 node
 129963 pts/8    00:00:02 node
 134451 pts/8    00:00:00 sh
 134452 pts/8    00:00:42 node
 136500 pts/10   00:00:00 sudo
 136503 pts/10   00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a nodejs process use more than 100% CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009933/can-a-nodejs-process-use-more-than-100-cpu)

Comment: `pstree` or just `ps -f` output might give you some hints as to what spawned which process.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, because you already wrote that it switches between cores and only one is at 80% at a time. It's not using two cores for JS execution, it's using one, just not always the same (based on whatever core the OS decides to assign it to at any given time). Plus, it may of course have other threads for things other than JS execution, like for libraries or file system operations, that result in that 5% used on the other core.